# php mongoclient - trying to query records that only have a "department" field

Tags: php, mongodb

I have made the following attempt to query documents that have a department value filled in:

```
            $collection = $this->mongo_db->db->selectCollection('widget');
            $result = $collection->find(
            array("department"=>array('$ne' => null),"department"=> array('$ne' => "")) 
            )->sort(['department'=>1]);
            return iterator_to_array($result);
```

But this is still returning documents that look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5824b9376b6347a422aae017"),
    "widgetnum" : "1840023",
    "last_assigned" : "missing"
}
```

I thought the

```
 "department"=>array('$ne' => null)
```

would have filtered this out.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For you perfect will be `$exists` operator.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/

Query should look something like this(select all documents where department exists and does not equal to `""`).

```
$collection = $this->mongo_db->db->selectCollection('widget');
$result = $collection->find(
        array( "department"=> array('$exists' => "true", '$nin': [""]) ) 
        )->sort(['department'=>1]);
return iterator_to_array($result);
```

Hope this helps.